# HTML.DropDownListFor selected issue

Tags: c#, razor, selected, html.dropdownlistfor

I've read through the various posts on here regarding this topic, but none are quite right. I'm simply trying to set the "30" value as "selected". The SelectListItem has value, text and selected as available arguments, but selected doesn't do anything from what I can see.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IndexThreshold, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "0", Value = "0" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "10", Value = "10" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "20", Value = "20" }, new SelectListItem() { Selected = true, Text = "30", Value = "30", Selected = true}, new SelectListItem() { Text = "40", Value = "40" }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "50", Value = "50" } }, HtmlAttr.Create("value: IndexThreshold", isReadOnly))


[DataMember]
public int IndexThreshold { get; set; }


public class SelectListItem
{
    public SelectListItem();
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong (and this is existing code, I'm just trying to implement the 'selected' feature). Any suggestions on how to clean this up/fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Side note: I'm VERY new to this language, but not to programming, so bear with me as I stumble through the syntax and implementation. :)

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have to implement SelectedListItem. It is already implemented in System.Web.Mvc assembly.

Comment: Could you not just set IndexThreshold = 30?